# Regular Expression for a alphanumeric after a text

Tags: regex

This is my regular expression

```
(\b(serial|sheet))+(\s(number|code|no))+?\b
```

For the input :

```
Serial no
sheet no
Sheet Number
```

Requirement is to parse the text which contain:

```
Serial no : 2424ABC
Sheet No 5 (Without colon)
Sheet No : 5
Serial No = 5335ABC
```

How to escape a assignment character (if available) and parse the next alphanumeric character?

Comment: do you want this https://regex101.com/r/yU9sQ6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(\b(serial|sheet))+(\s(number|code|no))+?\b\s*[:=#~– ]*(.*)
```

You can try it here : https://regex101.com/r/rO2cX1/1

Answer (score 0):

To escape a assignment character, do `\=`.

To parse the alphanumeric characters, do `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` or simply `\w*`.

Comment: @Shashi You can group those together: `[=-#~]*`

Answer (score 0):

If the `=` is optional, you could replace the `\s` in the regular expression with `[=\s]` to allow either a space or an equals. Perhaps better and matching your example try `\s=?\s*`.

If may characters might be between the word and the number then perhaps use `\s[-=#~_]?\s*`. Note the `-` goes at the start, otherwise it will be interpreted as a range of characters. Namely `[a-f]` means `[abcdef]`, ie any of those six characters, whereas `[-af]` means any of those three characters.

Hence the regular expression becomes:

```
(\b(serial|sheet))+(\s[-=#~_]?\s*(number|code|no))+?\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

```
(serial\s+no|sheet\s*no)(\s*\:\s*)([a-z0-9]+)
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/kHfWBqp3Bs).

You can add further cases to the pattern in first group. I covered two cases separated by `|`.

You can find the alphanumeric value in last group of this pattern.

Please note that, this pattern is written as a case-insensitive pattern.

Comment: Please supply the details of this answer here on Stackoverflow. Link only answers are likely to be deleted.